# characters of irreducible representations, orthogonality relation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

I Want to prove that it's impossible that to irreducible representation
Xpi(g)≥0  for all g
(pi irreducible representations)
I am thinking about Second orthogonality relation, and to use the fact that characters of irreducible representations, they are orthonormal.
And inner product of two different representations equal to zero.
I cannot arrange my thoughts and do not know if I am in the right direction, I would be happy if someone can help, and I would be happy if there is someone who knows a better solution.

Comment: You must assume that your character assumes real values otherwise you do not have an ordering where you can compare its values to $0$.

Comment: Thx, Yeah its real values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $\chi$ is irreducible and not the principal character $1_G$, then $[\chi,1_G]=0$. So $[\chi,1_G]=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g)=0$. Hence $\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g)=0$. But if $\chi(g) \geq 0$ for all $g \in G$, then $0=\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g)=\chi(1)+\sum_{g \in G-\{1\}}\chi(g) \geq \chi(1) \geq 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: [χ,1G]=0 - Its the inner product ?

Comment: Yes. So this amounts to the sum of all values equals $0$. Can you finish deriving a contradiction?

Comment: I would be thankful if you helped finish it.

Comment: so This means that there are certainly negative values so it cannot be Xpi(g)≥0 for all g ?

Comment: See edit to my hint.

Comment: Thanks dear it helped me a lot,  just want to ask ∑g∈G−{1}χ(g)≥χ(1)  because of the assuming that χ(g)≥0 ?

Comment: Well, $\sum_{g \in G-\{1\}}\chi(g) \geq 0$ since you are assuming $\chi(g) \geq 0$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: By the way, if you deem my answer as the correct one, please tick it as such so that it gets a green check mark. Thanks!

Comment: I want to ask you one more Q, does this answer that u share is correct to prove that  it's impossible that to all g wich g isn't the trivial,  Xpi(g)≥0 for every i,  (pi irreducible representations). @Nicky Hekster .

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I shared another Q, I will be thankful if you can help me' this is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4089337/905247 . @Nicky Hekster